# What happened to Hide after he died

Tags: tokyo-ghoul

I didn't read the tokyo ghoul manga, but I was wondering what happened to Hide after he died. Cause in Tokyo Ghoul re Hide comes back to life, and when I looked it up on google it said Hide let Kaneki eat some of his face to regain his strength at the end of season 2 of Tokyo Ghoul. So did Hide come back to life as a ghoul or did he just never die.

Comment: Hide never died. The anime deviated from the manga and the scene where Kaneki was carrying Hide never happened in the manga. My suggestion: if you have time, read the manga (starting from Tokyo Ghoul). I tried watching the anime, too but dropped it while on Tokyo Ghoul: re. It was confusing and the manga cleared up everything.

Answer (score 2):

Already answered in comments by @W. Are

> Hide never died. The anime deviated from the manga and the scene where Kaneki was carrying Hide never happened in the manga. My suggestion: if you have time, read the manga (starting from Tokyo Ghoul). I tried watching the anime, too but dropped it while on Tokyo Ghoul: re. It was confusing and the manga cleared up everything.

Yes, **he had never died**, but lost/damaged his vocal organ since kaneki ate part of his face to regain some strength to fight. This thing doesn't actually affect the anime, so i don't think it's spoiler.

- Answered this only, since it still shows 0 answers, though @W. Are already answered in comments, nor i could comment there to ask him post this answer.